# Image color overlay in slider plugin, text above overlay (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using the meta slider plugin for Wordpress. A big part of my design is a grey overlay on the slider. I can manage to get the overlay but it goes over the caption in the slider.

I've tried a lot and I haven't been able to do this on my own. How do I get the text above the overlay?

Comment: Do you want the text "Home" and "About" over the slider? can you give an image of more or less what you want?

Comment: I don't know WP, but you need to put that overlay on the `<li>` as a background instead of positioning it on top. You can create a tiny png file (1x1 px) and set as background.

Comment: The text I want above the overlay is "De Bommel in Sneek, voor een hapje en een drankje" The problem is I can't relocate the overlay div because it's generated from within the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
.metaslider .caption-wrap {
    background: rgba(50,50,50, 0.4);
    padding-top:13%;
}

.overlay:before {
    background:none;
}
```

Keep in mind though, that the above css should be loaded after the slider.css has been loaded, in order for the css rules to have a higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

I just assigned a class called overlay in the metaslider caption box, then I edit the css under Customize mode.

```
.overlay img {
  background-color:white;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```